# How to display number selected while sliding JSlide

Tags: java, swing, jslider

I'm trying to make a JSlider object show it's value while you are dragging it for this bit of program:

```
    JPanel sliders = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,1));
    JSlider jslExtR = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL,-255,255,0);
    jslExtR.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
    jslExtR.setMinorTickSpacing(1);
    sliders.add(jslExtR);
```

I've found some information in the link down here, but it seemed to complicated and thought there had to be an easier way to do it.

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Swing_How_to/JSlider/Show_JSlider_value_while_dragging.htm

Any help or ideas would be really appreciated, thank you.

PS: I DID look on Stack Overflow but no answer asked my question.

Comment: If there is some less complicated way to do it, like displaying it when done, i'll take it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to make a JSlider object show it's value while you are dragging

You would use a `ChangeListener`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Sliders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html) for a basic example to get you started.

Keep a link to the Swing tutorial handy for tutorials on all Swing basics.

Comment: Actually I was reading it right now, though I can't find where it displays the value while you are dragging it. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: @TheTroll, look at the SliderDemo code at the statement that gets the "fps". If that statement is inside the "if statement" then the fps is set when you release the slider. If you want the value as it is dragged get rid of the if statement.